# Listing subdirectories 3 levels deep using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, subdirectory

I'd like to know if there is a better alternative to my following code (preferably using LINQ)

```
            #region List and filter directories to only 3 levels deep
            // List all subdirectories within main directory
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\pdftest\", "*" ,SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            List<string> subdirectories = new List<string>();

            //Filter away all main directories, now we are left with subdirectories 3 levels deep
            for (int i = 0; i<folders.Length; i++)
            {
                int occurences = folders[i].Split('\\').Length-1;
                if (occurences==4)
                    subdirectories.Add(folders[i]);             
            }
            #endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should do it.

```
        string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\pdftest\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(folder => folder.Split('\\').Length <= 4).ToArray();
```

Comment: The idea is not bad, but what happens if you start in folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework

Comment: I was merely replicating the functionality that was in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838048)'s comment, it is important to check how deep you are using the so-called 'root' default path.

```
string Root = "C:\pdftest\".TrimEnd('\\');
int RootLength = Root.Split('\\').Length;
string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\pdftest\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(folder => folder.Split('\\').Length <= RootLength+4).ToArray();
```